# How to unit test gin handlers for correct validation of uri params?

Tags: go, testing, go-gin

I need to test a set of gin handlers with dependencies. I have some successful unit tests up and running, mocking the gin context. I notice, however, that ShouldBindURI never works. The key passed to my repo mock is always empty.

I find this disturbing as it should be failing if it can't bind the key. I suspect this happens because it's unit tests, so I don't have a router telling it where to look for variables in the URL. Is there any way to tweak the gin context to fix this?

Simplified version of what I'm doing

```
type SomeHandler struct {
  Repo ParticularRepoInterface
  Queue Queuer
  Timeout time.Duration
}

func NewHandler(repo DatabaseInterface, queue Queuer) *SomeHandler {
  return &SomeHandler{
    Repo: repo.ParticularRepo(),
    Queue: queue,
    Timeout:   time.Second * 10,

}

func(ctrl *SomeHandler) List(c *gin.context) {
  ctx, cancelContext := context.WithTimeout(c.Request.Context(), ctrl.Timeout)
  defer cancelContext()

  var key SomeKey

  err := c.ShouldBindUri(&key)
  if err != nil {
    // handle BindError
  }

  thing, err := repo.List(ctx, key)
  if err != nil {
    // handle errors
  }

  c.JSON(http.StatusOk, thing)
}

// followed by the rest of CRUD.
```

Tests are unit tests, so I'm mocking the gin context. ParentID is the thing that gets bound in the key which is used to call List.

```
func TestThing(t *testing.T) {
  t.Parallel()
  assert := assert.New(t)
  gin.SetMode(gin.TestMode)
  now := time.Now().UTC()

  filledThing := Thing{
    ParentID: gofakeit.UUID(),
    ThingID: gofakeit.UUID(),
    Time: &now
  }

  nilThing := Thing{
    ParentID: gofakeit.UUID(),
    ThingID: gofakeit.UUID(),
    Time: nil,
  }
  
  t.Run("Success", func(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    var key SomeKey
    parentID := gofakeit.UUID()
    mockThingList := []*Thing{&nilThing, &filledThing}

    mockQueue := NewMockQueue()
    repo := new(mocks.MockThingRepo)
    repo.On("List", mock.AnythingOfType("*context.valueCtx"), key).Return(mockThingList, nil)

    handler := handlers.NewThing(mockRepo, mockQueue)
    url := "/parents/" + parentID + "/things"
    recorder := httptest.NewRecorder()
    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    assert.NoError(err)
    request.RequestURI = url

    context, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(recorder)
    context.Request = request

    handler.List(context)

    expectedResponse, err := json.Marshal(mockThingList)
    assert.NoError(err)

    // more assert tests
  }

}
```

Comment: how is `SomeKey` defined?

Comment: `type SomeKey struct {
  ParentID string ``uri:"parent_id"`` 
}`

only single backtics

Comment: Simplify your test code [doc](https://gin-gonic.com/docs/testing/)

Answer (score 1):

You should mock a Http request than use gin to handle it, not just use your handler directly.

```
func TestContext(t *testing.T) {
assert := assert.New(t)

// setup test gin
w := httptest.NewRecorder()
c, e := gin.CreateTestContext(w)

type Parent struct {
    ParentID string
}
handler := func(ctx *gin.Context) {
    var s Parent
    if err := ctx.ShouldBindUri(&s); err != nil {
        ctx.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
        return
    }
    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, s)
}

// register handler to test gin
e.GET("/parents/:ParentID/things", handler)
request, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/parents/123/things", nil)
c.Request = request

// execute handler
responseRecorder := httptest.NewRecorder()
e.ServeHTTP(responseRecorder, request)

// assert your result
assert.Equal(http.StatusOK, responseRecorder.Code)
assert.Equal(`{"ParentID":"123"}`, responseRecorder.Body.String())
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully figured out how to do this, sans setting up a router.

Two steps, first ShouldBindUri checks the context for params, so add the route variable to the params before calling the controller.

```
context, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(recorder)
context.Request = request

param := gin.Param{Key: "parent_id", Value: parentID}
context.Params = append(context.Params, param)
controller.Index(context)
```

second, you need to setup the ginValidator upgrade, or ShouldBindUri will not validate on bind. You should be doing this already on your main server. [Link to guide](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/v9/_examples/gin-upgrading-overriding/v8_to_v9.go). Adding that to tests is a one-liner - `binding.Validator = new(GinValidator)`

And now calling the controller directly works as expected.